# MassTransit SQS unable to get exception stracktrace in error queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, masstransit

Currently I am using .net framework (4.7.2) with MassTransit(v8.0.15) to publish and consumer messages in RabbitMQ and SQS. Whenever I face any exception while consuming messages I am able to see stracktrace in RabbitMQ, but not in SQS. As per my understanding it had something to do with SQS headers limitation. But recently I have ungraded MassTransit to **8.1.2** in both of my application and in RabbitMQ I am receiving 2 messages in error queue for single message. 1st message is similar as before it conations the original message and **MT-Fault** headers and 2nd message contains

```
"message": {

    "faultId": "",

    "faultedMessageId": "",

    "timestamp": "",

    "exceptions": [

      {

        "exceptionType": "",

        "innerException": ,

        "stackTrace": "",

        "message": "",

        "source": "",

        "data": null

      }

    ],

    "host": {},

    "faultMessageTypes": [

      "urn: "

    ]
```

here I am able to see the exception details. I wanted to check if same message can be received in SQS as it contains stacktrace and would be helpful in debugging errors.

After MassTransit version upgrade I tried if same message is being received in SQS, but I am unable to get that message which contains exception details

Comment: Reviewing logs is even more helpful. You are correct that SQS header limitations prevent the stack trace from being in the headers. The message body above is from a `Fault<T>` message, not the original message. Fault messages include the full exception detail.

Comment: Is there a way I can get **Fault<T>** message in SQS ?

Comment: https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/exceptions#faults

Comment: After reviewing topics I realised there were no topics for Fault messages. Once I created those topics my problem got resolved. Looks like MassTransit does not create topics for fault messages through consumer applications.